# Create table from a previous prepared statemt

Tags: mysql

Hi i've got something like this as part of a more complex query:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Rather than executing the stmt itself i want to create a table from the result of the execute.

```
Create table A as select * from (Execute stmt)
```

gives me error

EDIT: 
Here's the entire stuff:

```
    Use catdatabase;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN columnA = "'  ,columnA, '"THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS "'  ,columnA, '"'))
INTO @sql
FROM
  tableB;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT columnB, Count(*) total, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM tableA inner join tableB on tableA.columnC = tableB.columnE where tableA.columnD <> "catpoop"
                   GROUP BY columnB');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: what is the value in stmt or what it contain selected value are tables; what is the error?

Comment: inside @sql there's a query. The error is table execute doesn't exist.

Comment: Please share your @sql query

Comment: u can't create a table that way 'create table A select * from (execute stmt)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you want to pivot your data and wants to save into temporary table. 
I have updated your query, Please check out this:

```
Use catdatabase;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN columnA = "'  ,columnA, '"THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS "'  ,columnA, '"'))
INTO @sql
FROM
tableB;

SET @sql = CONCAT('Create temporary table temp SELECT columnB, Count(*) total, ', @sql, ' FROM tableA inner join tableB on tableA.columnC = tableB.columnE where tableA.columnD <> "catpoop"
               GROUP BY columnB');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If you get any error in this just let me know.

Comment: i don't think you're that clear about the create table here

Comment: This is the only way to create table inside statements. By the way What error you are getting with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
set @table='t2';
SET @table1 = 'test';
set @a = concat('create table ',@table,' select * from ',@table1);
prepare stmt1 from @a;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

updated:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN columnA = "'  ,columnA, '"THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS "'  ,columnA, '"'))
INTO @sql
FROM
  tableB;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT columnB, Count(*) total, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM tableA inner join tableB on tableA.columnC = tableB.columnE where tableA.columnD <> "catpoop"
                   GROUP BY columnB');
set @new_sql = concat ('create table A',@sql);
PREPARE stmt FROM @new_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: ****Rather than executing the stmt itself i want to create a table from the result of the execute.*** what is not clear about my sentence to you guys?